# EF - Entity Sql contains clausule with string

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have one question about EF. If I understand correctly EF does not support Contains. I try to achieve this: I have column(nvarchar) with this: for ex.row1. 1;3;4;5,row2. 3;4;6 row3. 7;8;16 etc.
I have list(of string) with 1,6. My goal is to get row1 and row2 in result set.
I try with linq to entity and with linq to sql but i can't get this right.

I stuck with this and any help would be appreciated...
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to Entities *does* support the `string.Contains(string)` method, in all versions of the EF. Same for LINQ to SQL. There is a different Contains which requires EF 4, but that's not the droid you're looking for.